# transmissions of variables in a loop inside a function

Tags: javascript, variables

**Hello everyone !!!**

Here I have a tit problem of transmissions of variables, I am a beginner and it is the kind of problem which slows me down too much ... So instead of tinkering I prefer finally to have a more constructive answer.

the code in question:

```js
function displayAllPosts (post, postId, postContent, userUsername, divCol){
  console.log(divCol)
  console.log(postId)
  console.log(postContent)
  console.log(post)

  for (var i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    // Card qui affiche les posts et comments:

    // Card:
    let postAndComment = createTag('div')
    addClass(postAndComment, ['postAndComment'])
    postAndComment.setAttribute('id','postAndComment_' + postId)

    // Frame de la card:
    let divReadPost = createTag('div')
    addClass(divReadPost, ['display-frameCard__read-post', 'shadow', 'rounded'])

    // Injecte dans le html:
    divCol   .appendChild(postAndComment)
    postAndComment.appendChild(divReadPost)

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    // Intérieur de la card:

    // Cadre Username:
    let divDisplayUsername = createTag('div')
    addClass(divDisplayUsername, ['display-frameCard__username'])

    //Username:
    let divUsername = createTag('h2')
    divUsername.innerHTML = userUsername

  }
}
```

So in argument I place the variables: post, postId, postContent, userUsername, divCol.

In my console log, it works but it gives me the wrong answer to the variable, so either but it works, then once in the loop impossible this last does not know them ..
I have tinkered several ways but I'm there not happened.
Do you have any advice or solutions?
I would like to remind you that I am a beginner.
Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

** Update for # Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy :
for example for the variable divCol (response expected the selection of the html line) it returns me undefine while post returns this line to me while it must return me a list of post that it returns me all the same see the image from line 213:

[image]

Comment: " it works but it gives me the wrong answer to the variable". What is that variable and whats the value expected and received?

Comment: What is `addClass`? Does it differ from [`.classList.add`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre], along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I updated my post to answer your question.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, addClass is a shorter function of .classList.add.
I updated my post I hope this partly answers your question.

Comment: `divCol` is a function parameter. So it depends on how the function is being called.